# Tab limited exceeded? ‘Undefined tab position’

Tags: tabbing

I'm using latex to do syntactical analysis, using the following specifications:

```
 For super-script \tss{super-script}
\newcommand*{\tss}[1]{\textsuperscript{#1}}
\newcommand\tabspace{1cm}           % Adjust tab length here
\newcommand\mytabs{\hspace{\tabspace}\=\hspace{\tabspace}\=\hspace{\tabspace}\=\hspace{\tabspace}\=\hspace{\tabspace}\=}    

\newenvironment{syntax}[1][\mytabs] % The syntax environment, used for syntactical analyses
  {\begin{tabbing}#1\kill}
  {\end{tabbing}}
\newcommand{\tab}[2][\>]{#1 #2}     % Tab command, used in syntactical analyses
```

Currently, I can make five times `\tab`. My question is how I can change the number of possible `\tab`(s), so at to make it larger.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: well you have 5 tabs set in `\mytabs` which can obviously be extended, but `tabbing` is a pretty useless latex environment so often it's best not to base the markup on tabbing. It is hard to offer any advice given the lack of information in the question. Please always make a _complete_  (small) document that shows what you are trying to do.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply add other twenty `\=\hspace{\tabspace}` commands in the definition of `\mytabs`, so as to have sufficient room for your tabbing environments.

Here's a different approach. The `syntax` environment has an optional argument (default 5) for the number of columns; the `syntax*` environment wants instead an explicit line to be `\kill`ed, for setting unequal tab spaces.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentEnvironment{syntax}{O{5}}
 {
  \begin{tabbing}
  \prg_replicate:nn { #1 } { \=\hspace{\tabspace} }\kill
 }
 {
  \end{tabbing}
 }
\NewDocumentEnvironment{syntax*}{m}
 {
  \begin{tabbing}
  #1\kill
 }
 {
  \end{tabbing}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand\tabspace{1cm}           % Adjust tab length here
\newcommand{\tab}[2][\>]{#1#2}

\begin{document}

\begin{syntax}
\tab{a}\tab{b}\tab{c}\tab{d}\tab{e}\\
\tab{1}\tab{2}\tab{3}\tab{4}\tab{5}
\end{syntax}

\begin{syntax}[6]
\tab{a}\tab{b}\tab{c}\tab{d}\tab{e}\tab{f}\\
\tab{1}\tab{2}\tab{3}\tab{4}\tab{5}\tab{6}
\end{syntax}

\begin{syntax*}{\=aaa\=bbb\=ccccccc\=d}
\tab{a}\tab{b}\tab{c}\tab{d}\\
\tab{1}\tab{2}\tab{3}\tab{4}
\end{syntax*}

\end{document}
```

[image]